# Counting the number of elements with the same class- jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `ul` element. now I would like to know  how many of `li`'s have `selected` class .

```
<ul class="icon-list icon-list-inline star-rating" id="star-rating">

        <li class="selected"></li>
        <li class=""></li>
        <li class=""></li>
        <li class=""></li>
        <li class=""></li>
</ul>


var vote_selected = $('#star-rating ... ???').length;
```

it must return 1 .

Comment: What is interesting here is I tried to find a duplicate because I was sure there was one - The duplicate questions are not as specific as this one so the answers would need some work do be as definitive as @Ori_Drori's

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :-

```
var vote_selected = $('#star-rating li[class="selected"]').length;
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/n0cfdxup/46/)

Or (as `li` is immediate descendents of `#star-rating` you can use `>`).

```
var vote_selected = $('#star-rating > li[class="selected"]').length;
```

Or

```
var vote_selected = $('#star-rating > .selected').length;
```

Answer (score 6):

Use child selector with class:

```js
var vote_selected = $('#star-rating > .selected').length;

alert(vote_selected);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="icon-list icon-list-inline star-rating" id="star-rating">
  <li class="selected"></li>
  <li class=""></li>
  <li class=""></li>
  <li class="selected"></li>
  <li class=""></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think the `>` is unnecessary. The `li`'s will always be immediate children of the `ul`.

Comment: What if one of the `li` have a `ul` inside, which also have `li` inside it? In general it's better to be as specific as possible.

Comment: @Rahul It depends on your needs that '>' is extra or not

Comment: Good answer. - Better than the ones I found to close this question as a duplicate so I didn't

Answer (score 1):

Check this,

```
var vote_selected = $('#star-rating li.selected').length;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12036795)

Comment: @Hidde Actually, this does answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

```js
alert($('#star-rating li.selected').length)//use selector li.selected
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="icon-list icon-list-inline star-rating" id="star-rating">

        <li class="selected"></li>
        <li class=""></li>
        <li class=""></li>
        <li class=""></li>
        <li class=""></li>
</ul>
```

Use selector ex. `li.classname`